# How to create 'Lightweight Tags' using Git publisher plugin in jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

im using **Git Publisher** plugin to create tags in git repository, basically what Git Publisher does is, it creates a tag and pushing it to the git repository but what i need is to create a lightweight tag and push to the repository.

I tried specifying **v1.0.0.1-lw** as tag name and ran the jenkins job but still it is creating the tag and not lightweight tag.

Comment: Why do you need a lightweight tag?

Comment: Lightweight are more appropriate for private use, that means tagging special commits to be able to find them again. lightweight does not save the information of who tagged, when it was tagged and the changelog, but i dont require those information since im going to create tags using one user account and i can get those information from that commit id itself.

Comment: I understand that you do not **need** annotated tags, but if a tool only creates those (since presumably it was made for use with more than one user), what is the big deal? They only take up a tiny bit more space on your hard disk.

Comment: i want to tag the commit before the changes goes for testing so i wanted to use lightweight tag and the changelog will be sent in mail using jenkins editable email notification plugin, only for the release versions i wanted to use annotated tag, and i was looking if someone who has achieved it earlier or is there an option to do it? if there is no option then i'll be using annotated tags itself.